# Angular JS: data binding with dynamically added html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am facing problems with two way data binding in angular js. Here is the sample code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="">

<div>

<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>

<div id="jack">
</div>
<script>
    $("document").ready(function(){
        $("#jack").append("<p ng-bind='name'></p>");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Over here I am dynamically adding a paragraph with ng-bind to a div called jack using jQuery**

For some reason when I type something in input box it is not reflecting in paragraph with ng-bind property.

I am a novice in angular js and would request you to provide me a simple solution to tackle this issue.

Comment: use ng-include instead of jquery and $.append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use jQuery to modify DOM outside Angular this way. Angular does not know about that binding as it was not compiled by Angular.

To solve this particular sample, simply remove the jQuery script and change the HTML to this:

```
<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<p ng-bind="name"></p>
```

The example above will work, but I imagine this was not a real-world example. If you post a more specific scenario, I can update my answer to help you solve that.

**Edit**

Based on your comment, I would create a simple directive to which you could pass your template, it would compile the template and inject the compiled template in the DOM.

Directive:

```
function myTemplateCompile($compile) {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: link
  }

  function link(scope, elem, attrs) {

    attrs.$observe('template', (template) => {
      elem.html(template);
      $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
    });

  }

}
```

HTML

```
<my-template-compile template="any HTML you might need including bindings"></my-template-compile>
```

You can then change the template attribute of the directive on the fly and it will re-compile and update the DOM based on the new value.

The example above should point you in the right direction. I just have to warn you, that this might be quite dangerous. If the content you are injecting is coming from some user input, this might have **very severe** security implications. Please make sure you are not exposing your application to attacks.

Comment: As you have suggested the code will work. And that was how it was before I made changes to code.

Comment: I am trying to fetch html (embedded with data-model and data-bind) using ajax and appending them into my form using jquery.

Comment: I posted a more specific example. I hope it will point you to the right direction.

Comment: My requirement changed. So, I took care of the problem in the way you had suggested first.

Comment: Ok, I am glad you made it work. Feel free to accept the answer as a reference for anyone who might find your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well first we need to define the app and create custom directive.

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[])
                 .controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
                      $scope.name="Your name";   
                 })
   myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
         return {
                 restrict: 'E',
                 template: '<span data-ng-bind="name"></span>'
         };
   });
```

After this you need to use above created directive as like below

```
<my-Directive></my-Directive>
```